# combobox not bound to my value

Tags: silverlight, binding, combobox, code-behind

I know, there are a lot of examples but I'm not getting it to work.

I have a Silverlight Mask where I dynamically add UIElements like Textboxes or ComboBoxes. So far, this is working fine. Now I'm trying to set the ComboBox Selected Item from my database values.

I store the information for generation in my own classes.

```
public class Metadata
{
    public int? MetadataId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public MetaDataType MetaDataType { get; set; }
    public List<MetadataData> MetadataData { get; set; }
}

 public class MetadataData
{
    public int MetadataDataId { get; set; }
    public int MetadataId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}


public partial class MetadataStore
{
    public Guid MetadataStoreId { get; set; }
    public Guid ObjectId { get; set; }
    public Guid ModuleTypeId { get; set; }
    public int MetadataSetId { get; set; }
    public int? MetadataSetSetId { get; set; }
    public int MetadataId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? RowId { get; set; }
    public DataContainer.Profile userProfile { get; set; }
}
```

My selected value stores the MetadataDataId as a String in my MetadataStore in the field Description. I'm generating the UIElements based on the MetaData class in code-behind like this

```
switch ((MetaDataDataType)metadata.MetaDataType.MetaDataTypeId)
        {
            case MetaDataDataType.String:
                frmElement = new TextBox() { Name = String.Format("dynCtrl_{0}_{1}", metadata.MetadataId, metadata.Name)
                    AcceptsReturn = false, Margin = new Thickness(4),
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                    Height = metadata.Height, Width = metadata.Width,
                    Style = App.Current.Resources["TextBoxStyleFlat"] as Style };
                frmElement.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty,
                    new Binding { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Path = new PropertyPath(metadata.Name) });
                break;

            case MetaDataDataType.SingleSelection:
                frmElement = new ComboBox()
                {
                    Name = String.Format("dynCtrl_{0}_{1}", metadata.MetadataId, metadata.Name),
                    Margin = new Thickness(4),
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                    Style = App.Current.Resources["ComboBoxStyleFlat"] as Style,
                    ItemsSource = metadata.MetadataData,
                    DisplayMemberPath = "Description",
                    //SelectedItem = metadata.Name,
                    Height = metadata.Height,
                    Width = metadata.Width
                };

                frmElement.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, new Binding { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Path = new PropertyPath(metadata.Name) });
                frmElement.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValuePathProperty, new Binding { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Path = new PropertyPath("MetadataDataId") });
                default:
                    break;
}
```

I thought I could make it work with an `Dictionary<string, object>`

```
var p = new Dictionary<string, object>();
p[mData.Metadata.Name] = Convert.ToInt32(item.Description);
```

but as it didn't work, I ended up with generating a `DataTable` and selecting the first element which gets me an `Object` with my desired dynamic properties.

```
TempObject.Testprop
TempObject.Nutzen
```

The DataSourceCreator is used from http://blog.bodurov.com/How-to-Bind-Silverlight-DataGrid-From-IEnumerable-of-IDictionary/.

```
internal static void generateDataContext(List<MetadataSetMetadata> metadataSetMetadata, List<MetadataStore> metadataStore, ref Grid viewGrid)
    {
        if (metadataStore != null && metadataStore.Count > 0)
        {

            dynamic expObj = new ExpandoObject();
            var p = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (var item in metadataStore.Where(x => x.MetadataSetSetId == null))
            {
                var mData = metadataSetMetadata.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Metadata != null && x.Metadata.MetadataId.Equals(item.MetadataId));

                switch ((MetaDataDataType)mData.Metadata.MetaDataType.MetaDataTypeId)
                {
                    case MetaDataDataType.String:
                    case MetaDataDataType.LongString:
                        p[mData.Metadata.Name] = item.Description;
                        break;
                    case MetaDataDataType.SingleSelection:
                        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Description))
                        {
                            p[mData.Metadata.Name] = Convert.ToInt32(item.Description);
                        }
                        break;                       
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            var emtyRowList = new List<IDictionary>();
            emtyRowList.Add(p);

            viewGrid.DataContext = DataSourceCreator.ToDataSource(emtyRowList).Cast<object>().FirstOrDefault();
            viewGrid.UpdateLayout();
        }
    }
```

I set the `DataContext` for the complete `StackPanel`. My `TextBox` shows the correct Text stored in TempObject.Testprop. My ComboBox` only displays its Items Source but its not showing my already selected item, which Id is stored in TempObject.Nutzen.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

UPDATE:
I could make it working, binding the SelectedValue to the MetadataData Object instead of its ID value and setting the SelectedValuePath to the ID property name of MetadataData.

Comment: You need to supply a binding to the combobox. What type is the items source? Because based on the displaymember path and selectedvaluepath it looks like a complex object while you are just setting selected item to a string

Comment: Thank you @Nkosi, I updated my question.

Comment: Show what you did for the TextBox. With all the changes you've made to the question I'm more confused now about your problem. May be I can get a better understanding if you show me what worked for the text box. I say this also because you indicate that you are doing binding when so far everything you shown does not involve binding at all.

Comment: @Nkosi I updated it again.Please have a look.

Comment: I got it working, but not while using the ID value but the whole object of MetadataData. Is it also possible without getting that object?

Comment: Glad you got it working. I'll remove my answer If it is no longer relevant. I saw from your updates that you were going down the right track. You should put the solution as an answer to your own question so that other can benefit from the solution.

Comment: With the combobox you need the whole object.

Comment: Thanks for the leading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it working, binding the SelectedValue to the MetadataData Object instead of its ID value and setting the SelectedValuePath to the ID property name of MetadataData.